# How can I get this query-set in a more efficient way using Django models?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

My **models.py** looks like this:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = 'user_posts')
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 140)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default = 0)

class Vote(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = 'user_votes')
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name = 'post_votes')
    is_voted = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = [('user', 'post')]
```

Let me explain how my voting system is set up. When a user votes for a post for the first time, a new Vote object is created. A user can down vote a post if he has voted for it first. In that case, the is_voted property in the Vote object is set to False.

Now in a view, I need a list of Posts which the user has upvoted. Which means a Vote object for the post and user combination exists, AND, the is_voted property of that object is True.

Here's how I am currently trying to do it:

**views.py**

```
def user_profile(request, pk):
    # Get user using pk
    u = User.objects.get(pk = pk)

    # Get a list of Votes using the user instance
    votes = Vote.objects.filter(user = u, is_voted = True)

    # Getting the list of posts using the votes list
    post_list = Post.objects.none() # Generating empty list
    for vote in votes:
        # Adding vote.post to post_list using chaining.
        .....
```

This actually works, but feels very hack-y. Is there any way to generate the query-set without the for loop? I am guessing I can use the related_name, but I am not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this queryset should give all posts upvoted by a user (I haven't tried it though):

```
votes = Post.objects.filter(post_votes__user=u, post_votes__is_voted=True)
```

It's a reverse lookup from the model to which points the foreign key to the model which contains it.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
post_list = [p.post for p in Vote.objects.filter(user = u, is_voted = True).select_related('post')]
```